# Зависание интерфейса

Tags: python, tkinter, время, while

Когда запускаю программу накапливаю клики и нажимаю авто клики программа намертво зависает. 
Причём в консоли результат пишется.

Как я понял ей не понравился цикл `while`.

Можно это как-то исправить?

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import math

tk = Tk()

tk['bg'] = 'orange'
tk.title('кликер')
tk.geometry('800x600')

tk.resizable(width=False, height=False)

clicks = 0

def click():
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    print(clicks)

def c100():
    global clicks
    if clicks >= 5:
        clicks -= 5
        while 1:
            clicks += 0.3
            print(round(clicks,1))
            time.sleep(1)
    elif clicks < 5:
        print("мало кликов")

canvas = Canvas(tk, height=300, width=250   )
canvas.pack()

frame = Frame(tk, bg='red')
frame.place(relx=0.06, rely=0.06, width=700, height=500)

title = Label(frame, text='кликер', bg='yellow', font=('Comic Sans MS', 40))
title.pack()
btn = Button(frame, text='клик', bg='blue', font=('Comic Sans MS', 20), width=30, height=1, command=click, activebackground='dark blue', activeforeground='white')
btn.pack()
title1.place(x=5, y=10)
btn2 = Button(frame, text='Авто клики\nЦена:5', bg='lime', font=('Comic Sans MS', 15), command=c100)
btn2.place(x=30, y=160)



tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: строчку title1.place(x=5, y=10) случайно написал не учитывайте её

Comment: когда запускаю программу накапливаю клики и нажимаю авто клики программа намертво зависает причём в консоли результат пишется как я понял ей не понравился цикл while можно это както исправить?

Comment: Можно, для этого while надо запустить в отдельном потоке

Comment: немного не понял что означает в отдельном потоке это как можете показать на коде пожалуйста

Comment: Опишите словами что должна делать программа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не понимаю логику вашей функции `c100()`.

Но вам надо запомнить что:

- **`while 1:`** - блокирует интерфейс;
- **`time.sleep(1)`** - блокирует интерфейс;
- вам надо использовать метод **`after()`**.

---

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import math


tk = Tk()

tk['bg'] = 'orange'
tk.title('кликер')
tk.geometry('800x600')

tk.resizable(width=False, height=False)

clicks = 0

def click():
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    print(f'clicks = {clicks}')

def c100(fl=1):
    global clicks
    #print(f'def c100(): {clicks}') #
    
    '''   попробуйие так
    if fl:
    
        if clicks >= 5:
            clicks -= 5
            canvas.after(1000, lambda: c100(0))            
        elif clicks < 5:
            print("мало кликов")    
    else:
        clicks += 0.3
        print(round(clicks, 1))
        canvas.after(1000, lambda: c100(0)) 
        
    '''    

# мне показалось ято так:    
    if clicks >= 5 and fl:
        clicks -= 5 if fl else 0
#        while 1:
        clicks += 0.3
        print(round(clicks, 1))

#            time.sleep(1)
        canvas.after(1000, lambda: c100(0))
    if not fl:
        clicks += 0.3
        print(round(clicks, 1))
        canvas.after(1000, lambda: c100(0))    
            
    elif clicks < 5:
        print("мало кликов")    
    
    
    
    '''     попробуйие так
    if clicks >= 5:
        clicks -= 5
#        while 1:
        clicks += 0.3
        print(round(clicks, 1))

#            time.sleep(1)
        canvas.after(1000, c100)
            
    elif clicks < 5:
        print("мало кликов")
    '''

canvas = Canvas(tk, height=300, width=250)
canvas.pack()

frame = Frame(tk, bg='red')
frame.place(relx=0.06, rely=0.06, width=700, height=500)

title = Label(frame, text='кликер', bg='yellow', font=('Comic Sans MS', 40))
title.pack()

btn = Button(
    frame, 
    text='клик', 
    bg='blue', font=('Comic Sans MS', 20), 
    width=30, height=1, 
    command=click, 
    activebackground='dark blue', activeforeground='white'
)
btn.pack()

#title1.place(x=5, y=10)

btn2 = Button(frame, text='Авто клики\nЦена:5', bg='lime', font=('Comic Sans MS', 15), command=c100)
btn2.place(x=30, y=160)

tk.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: суть в том чтобы когда ты нажимаешь на клик у тебя накапливались клики и потом ты нажимаешь авто клики и они начинают сами накапливатся

Comment: @Dimonset , мне казалось, что я вам ответил на то, что вы спрашиваете в комментариях. Что не так  в трех вариантах. которые я вам предложил в своем примере?

Comment: Спасибо огромное правдо я половину кода не понимаю но вы гений! Спасибо вам!

Comment: @Dimonset пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: я поставил ещё раз спасибо!